# Are my calculations for stepping down from 240v to 208v correct?

Tags: electrical, 240v, voltage

I just bought a used UPS and didn't realize I bought 208v and not the 240v version. So I'm looking for a buck-boost transformer. Both input and output are at 30amps.

I think I've done the math right.

240v-208v=32v

32v*30amp=960va

So I'm looking for a 16v/32v 1kVA buck-boost transformer. Am I right here? Do I need more VA for tolerances?

(Updated)

The wires are 2+G 10 gauge wiring. The UPS has an L6-30P (male) tail and I've got an L6-30R socket ready to install once I figure out the transformer setup.

UPS Specs: https://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/APC-Smart-UPS-5000VA-208V-Rackmount-Tower/P-SUA5000RMT5U

Feed Circuit:
[image: Feed Circuit]

UPS Input Label:
[image: UPS Input Label]

Comment: Ummm picture of the nameplate please?  Transformers have a fixed step up or step down ratio.  In your case you would want a step down transformer.  The transformer has to provide VA for the current and 208V you *are* using, *not the 32V that goes unused*.  Your total input will equal output *plus losses*.

Comment: Oh and full specs of the circuit you want to feed it from as well pls.

Comment: Do your loads *really really need* 240V? Most things people put UPSs on aren't picky.

Comment: I checked, and turns out using 208V UPSs in a 240V environment is specifically warned against: https://www.apc.com/us/en/faqs/FA156614/

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica it's the input specs of the UPS that are the concern, by the sound of things

Comment: Yup, user37575614 is correct, the UPS can't handle 240v. This I'm looking into a buck-boost transformer.

Comment: What is the rated output of the UPS at 208?

Comment: Max output is 4.0kWatts / 5.0kVA. 

Here are specs on the UPS. 
https://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/APC-Smart-UPS-5000VA-208V-Rackmount-Tower/P-SUA5000RMT5U

Comment: Again, a transformer, or shared core inductor *can* be used as a *part* in a buck, boost, or buck/boost converter, but these are DC converters, although they can be *parts* of AC circuits.  What you want is just a correctly sized step down transformer.  No buck or boost effect.

Comment: I take it you got the UPS second-hand, or why can't you take it back to where you bought it and get the 240V version instead?

Comment: A 3kVA transformer can easily be around 50 pounds. If it's an autotransformer it would be a bit less. They cost at least $100 even if you find a good deal on a used one. Are you willing to widen the taps on the transformer in the UPS (as the link talks about) and also modify the circuit board in the UPS so it thinks it's getting 208 instead?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It was bought used at a great price and can't be returned. I don't mind spending a little bit for the proper equipment. I'd still be getting a good deal. I'm just trying to get the right equipment and be safe.